# Get text between two signs in a sentence

Tags: python, string

The task is to get text between two signs in a sentence.
User input sentence in one line in next one he input signs(for this case it's [ and ]).

Example:

```
In this sentence [need to get] only [few words].
```

Output needs to look like:

```
need to get few words
```

Can someone have any clue how to do this?

I have some idea like split input so we will access every element of the list and if a first sign is [ and finish with ] we save that word to other list, but there is a problem if the word doesn't end with ]

**P.S. user will never input empty string or have a sign inside sign like `[word [another] word]`.**

Comment: Kindly provide an example of your question. This will help to provide a more clear and robust answer.

Comment: If you carefully read the text you will see I did that.

Comment: You've done it, but the formatting is incorrect which makes it difficult to understand clearly.

Comment: Edited, I hope it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like this:

```
import re

your_string = "In this sentence [need to get] only [few words]"
matches = re.findall(r'\[([^\[\]]*)]', your_string)
print(' '.join(matches))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iVyoaM/1)

2. Solution without regex:

```
your_string = "In this sentence [need to get] only [few words]"

result_parts = []
current_square_brackets_part = ''
need_to_add_letter_to_current_square_brackets_part = False
for letter in your_string:
    if letter == '[':
        need_to_add_letter_to_current_square_brackets_part = True
    elif letter == ']':
        need_to_add_letter_to_current_square_brackets_part = False
        result_parts.append(current_square_brackets_part)
        current_square_brackets_part = ''
    elif need_to_add_letter_to_current_square_brackets_part:
        current_square_brackets_part += letter
print(' '.join(result_parts))
```

Comment: Didn't learn that yet.Is there any other way?Maybe easier and beginner?

Comment: Updated answer with solution without regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re
text = 'In this sentence [need to get] only [few words] and not [unbalanced'


' '.join(re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', text))
```

Output: `'need to get few words'`

Or `'(?<=\[).*?(?=\])'` as regex using lookarounds

Comment: Didn't learn that yet.Is there any other way?Maybe easier and beginner?

Comment: @Kalaba I provided. [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455922/16343464) without regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more classical solution using parsing.

It reads the string character by character and keeps it only if a flag is set. The flag is set when meeting a [ and unset on ]

```
text = 'In this sentence [need to get] only [few words] and not [unbalanced'

add = False
l = []
m = []
for c in text:
    if c == '[':
        add = True
    elif c == ']':
        if add and m:
            l.append(''.join(m))
        add = False
        m = []
    elif add:
        m.append(c)
out = ' '.join(l)
print(out)
```

Output: `need to get few words`